# Open Links Inside of an iframe Outside of the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've used an iframe code similar to:

```
<iframe src="/comment_contents.php?profile_id=2850" height="100%" width="100%" style="border: none;">
</iframe>
```

inside a Bootstrap Modal in an another page (/profile_comments.php?profile_id=2850).

HTML contents inside the iframe page (/comment_contents.php?profile_id=2850) are something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/comment_contents.php?profile_id=2850" class="form-comment">
  <div class="form-comment-contents">
    <input type="text" name="comment" value="" class="comment-text">
    <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="comment-submit">
    <br><br>
    <a href="/view_profile.php?id=2851">
      <img src="img/profile2851.jpg" class="circle-comments" alt="Emma Watson">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-text lead">You are just awesome!</div>
    <br>
    <a href="/view_profile.php?id=2852">
      <img src="img/profile2852.jpg" class="circle-comments" alt="Bill Gates">
    </a>
    <div class="comment-text lead">You are Cool!</div>
  </div>
</form>.
```

You may have noticed there is a code:

```
<a href="/view_profile.php?id=2852">...</a>
```

So, when a person clicks on it, a Profile View page opens inside the iframe. But I want link to be opened not in the iframe, but in the outside. I mean, in the URL bar.

Is there any javaScript or something else to open the link URL (inside the iframe) in the URL Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `target="_top"` to that link

```
<a href="/view_profile.php?id=2851" target="_top"><img src="img/profile2851.jpg" class="circle-comments" alt="Emma Watson"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you preferring to open the link in a new tab and not in the same tab?

You could try this..

a href="/view_profile.php?id=2852" target="_blank">...

I used target="_blank" that allows you to open the link in a new tab. This Link might be of help, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp .